# What are the tasks that android studio run when I click run button?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

What are the tasks that android studio run when I click the "run button"?

I mean this button with the green right arrow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have not cropped that image, because on the left box of the Run-Button are the tasks listed. Most of the time there are gradle tasks like build/run more specifically your recent executed tasks (history).

Answer (score 0):

There is "Build" tab at the bottom of Android Studio, which shows step-by-step information about what's going on at the moment.

[image]